# What does this Erlang statement do?

Tags: erlang

I have this [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) code:

```
not lists:any(fun(Condition) ->Condition(Message) end, Conditions).
```

Can anyone please explain the entire statement in layman's terms?   For your information `Condition` is a function, `Conditions` is an array. What does `fun(Condition) ->Condition(Message) end` mean? As well as meaning of `not lists:any`.

Comment: For reference: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#any-2

Comment: For reference, it is the same as:
lists:all(fun(Condition) -> not Condition(Message) end, Conditions).

Comment: For reference, this is the application of one of De Morgan's Laws :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fun(Condition) ->Condition(Message) end
```

is a lambda function that applies the function `Condition` to the value of `Message` (taken as a closure on the surrounding code).

```
lists:any
```

is a function that takes a predicate and a list of values, and calls the predicate on each value in turn, and returns the atom `true` if any of the predicate calls do.

Overall, the result is the atom `true` if none of the `Condition` functions in the list `Conditions` return `true` for the `Message` value.

EDIT -- add documentation for `lists:any`

```
any(Pred, List) -> bool()
```

Types:

```
Pred = fun(Elem) -> bool()
 Elem = term()
List = [term()]
```

Returns true if `Pred(Elem)` returns true for at least one element `Elem` in List.

Comment: eh the result is inverted ("not lists::any(.."

Comment: For the hard of reading : "Overall, the result is true if _none_ of the Condition functions return true"

Comment: you edited your post Steve?  I don't see the 'edit' diff thing.

Comment: Yeah -- I added the section starting with "EDIT -- "

Comment: yet the wiki diff thing doesn't show (for me).  Anyone can see it?

Only I'd swear that I saw you had it inverted before the edit, but I'll believe you if you now tell me that I'm hard of reading ;)

Answer (score 1):

Condition is something that takes a message and returns a boolean if it meets some criteria.

The code goes through the list of conditions and if *any* of them say true then it returns false, and if *all* of them say false it says true.

Roughly translated to verbose pseudo-[Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

```
def not_lists_any(Message,Conditions):
  for Condition in Conditions:
    if Condition(Message):
      return False
  return True
```

Answer (score 1):

One step behind syntax and stdlib description which you have in other answers:

This code looks very much like an Erlang implementation of [chain-of-responsibility design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). The message (in [OOP sense of the word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Messages)) "traverses" all possible handlers (functions from `Conditions` array) until someone can handle it. By the author's convention, the one which handles the message returns `true` (otherwise `false`), so if nobody could handle the message the result of your expression as a whole is `true`:

```
% this is your code wrapped in a function
dispatch(Message, Handlers) ->
    not lists:any(fun(Condition) ->Condition(Message) end, Handlers).
```

It may be used like this:

```
CantHandle = dispatch(Event, Handlers),
if CantHandle->throw(cannot_handle); true->ok end.
```